# Change caption off a Messagebox shown from CA

Tags: wix

I'm using Session.Message to spawn a Messegebox from some CA. Is there a way to change Caption on a spawned Messagebox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe MsiProcessMessage exposes that.  Hope I am wrong.